# Making your Office 365 App Available to Multiple Organizations

Tags: office365, windows-store

I'm building Windows Store app that consume Office 365 API Preview to fetch Active Directory data (e.g. users, groups, contacts, etc) and It works just fine when I authenticate using admin account of the same tenant which I registered the O365 API with it by defualt the Office 365 App properties was "Make this app available to" was for "Multiple Organizations" as I want to make your application available to all Office 365 users.  This means, users not only from my Office 365 tenant, but also from other tenants will be able to log in and use my application. but when I tested the app using admin account from different office 365 tenant It failed with "Authenticate failed error" exception

Comment: Hello Amr, did you find a solution for this problem?!